# NSUserDefaults Contains Value Or Not?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

How to know whether `NSUserDefaults` contains any value?How to check whether its empty?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There isn't a way to check whether an object within NSUserDefaults is empty or not.
However, you can check whether a value for particular key is nil or not.

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSObject * object = [prefs objectForKey:@"your_particular_key"];
if(object != nil){
   //object is there
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSUserDefaults *data = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
NSString *string = [data objectForKey:@"yourKey"];
if(string==nil)
NSlog(@"nil")
```

Take a look at [NSUserDefault documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
// For saving the values
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
// saving an NSString
[userDefaults setObject:@"Ttest" forKey:@"key"];
// --- For Retrieving

NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
// getting an NSString
NSString *myString = [userDefaults stringForKey:@"key"];
```

Comment: You should compare to nil, not NULL, as @Krishnabhadra states.

Answer (score 0):

To check whether a specific value is set or not, no matter of its location (global or application's), check the returned value of `-[NSUserDefaults objectForKey:]`

```
id obj = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"My-Key-Name"];
if (obj != nil) {...}
```

To check if the application (bundle) has any settings stored in user defaults:

```
NSUserDefaults* sdu = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString* bundleId = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
NSDictionary* mainBundleSettings = [sdu persistentDomainForName:bundleId];

NSLog(@"%@", mainBundleSettings);
```

If you are interested in all possible values for which `-[NSUserDefaults objectForKey:]` will return something, including system global settings, simply call

```
NSDictionary* allPossibleSettings = [sdu dictionaryRepresentation];
```

`NSUserDefaults` is never empty. It combines global settings, bundle's settings, temporary data and maybe something else. For example, if you call:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"NSBoldSystemFont"]
```

you will get the `@"LucidaGrande-Bold"` string value which will be taken from global settings, even when your application has never set this value.